# Short circuited or

Tags: xpath, xquery

Is there a way to do a short circuited or operator in XQuery like you can do in C#, Java, JavaScript, etc?

I have some XML that can be in two formats,  either:

```
<sometag>
  <bodytext>
    <section>
      <bodytext>
        <h1>Some html here</h1>
        <h2>Some more html</h2>
      </bodytext>
    </section>
  </bodytext>
</sometag>
```

or

```
<sometag>
  <bodytext>
        <h1>Some html here</h1>
        <h2>Some more html</h2>
  </bodytext>
</sometag>
```

I'm trying to return the html that's inside the inner body text tag.  If i do

```
/sometag/bodytext/section/bodytext/*
```

will return the first scenario

```
/sometag/bodytext/*
```

it will return the  second scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can always use `/sometag/innermost(.//bodytext)/*` if the function is supported by your XQuery processor or version. Or `/sometag//bodytext[not(.//bodytext)]/*`.

Comment: sometag//bodytext[not(.//bodytext)]/ worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a simple if-then-else condition:

```
let $v1 := /sometag/bodytext/section/bodytext/*
let $v2 := /sometag/bodytext/*
return 
  if (fn:exists($v1)) 
  then $v1 
  else (
    $v2
  )
```

Comment: This looks useful, but I don't think it will work in this scenario.